# simple program to calculate day not working

Tags: c, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write a simple program, that outputs the day given a date, using 1/1/0001 as Saturday. I have written the program, but have passed about 4 hours just to find some mistake which is making my answer wrong. The correct answer can be found here. http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=1&y1=1&d2=1&m2=1&y2=400&ti=on

The following is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long long int leap_days, days;

long long int *no_leap_years(int day, int month, long long int year){
    leap_days = (year-1)/4;
    leap_days -= (year-1)/100;
    leap_days += (year-1)/400;

    int is_leap;

    if(!(year%400)){
        is_leap = 1;
    } else if(!(year%100)){
        is_leap = 0;
    } else if(!(year%4)){
        is_leap = 1;
    } else {
        is_leap = 0;
    }

    printf("Leap year - %d\n", is_leap);
    printf("Leap days - %lld\n", leap_days);
    if(is_leap){
        if(month>2) leap_days++;
        else if(month==2){
            if(day>28) leap_days++;
        }
    }
    printf("Leap days - %lld\n", leap_days);
    return &leap_days;
}

long long int *no_of_days(int day, int month, long long int year){
    long long int leap_days = *no_leap_years(day, month, year);
    days = leap_days + (365*(year-1));
    if(month>1) days+=31;
    if(month>2) days+=28;
    if(month>3) days+=31;
    if(month>4) days+=30;
    if(month>5) days+=31;
    if(month>6) days+=30;
    if(month>7) days+=31;
    if(month>8) days+=31;
    if(month>9) days+=30;
    if(month>10) days+=31;
    if(month>11) days+=30;
    days+=day;
    printf("total - %lld\n", days);
    return &days;
}

char *day_computer(int day, int month, long long int year){
    long long int days = *no_of_days(day, month, year);
    printf("total - %lld\n", days);
    days %= 7;
    printf("remain - %lld\n", days);
    if(days==1) return "Saturday";
    else if(days==2) return "Sunday";
    else if(days==3) return "Monday";
    else if(days==4) return "Tuesday";
    else if(days==5) return "Wednesday";
    else if(days==6) return "Thursday";
    else return "Friday";
}

int main()
{
   int  dd = 1;
   int mm = 1;
   long long int yy = 400;

   printf("%s\n", day_computer(dd, mm, yy));

   return 0;
}
```

According to the website, total no.of days from 1/1/1 to 1/1/400 should be 145,735 days, but according to my code, it is 145732. I cannot find where I am missing 3 days. Please help me.

You may use this online editor to compile my program. http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: How many leap days would you expect over 400 years?  100, right?  Your program is reporting 96.

Comment: @FiddlingBits No.. actually nos. divisble by 100 and not 400, are not leap years. like 1900, 1800, 2100 are not. But 200, 400, 2000 are.

Comment: Study more the definition of leap years. Read more about C. Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

Answer (score 3):

The online calendar program is correct; then again, so is your code. The problem lies in the specific time period for which you are calculating.

Your code adjusts for leap years: every 4 years, except for centuries (which are not) and quad-centuries (which again *are*). However, both adjustments "once a century" were not observed in the [Julian Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar):

> The Julian reform lengthened seven months and replaced the intercalary month with an intercalary day to be added every four years to February.

For the period 46 BC - 4 October 1582, you should use the *Julian* way of calculating leap years. For dates after that "closing date" (which is **15 October 1582**), you can use the *Gregorian* (current) calculation.

Without the 2 adjustment for leap years in whole centuries, you get the same result as the online calendar.